# How can I get React.js TypeScript to accept 'parentElement' on 'event.target' with a onKeyDown event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, focus

I have a special accessible  element built with React TypeScript and I am trying to define keys to navigate it and to be able to focus within the table element. It is built specially for screen readers... However I just can not seem to get the types down.

I can not get rid of the following error:

**Property 'parentElement' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)**

here is the function I am trying to declare:

```
 const keyDownHandler = (event: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      (event.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild as HTMLButtonElement).focus();
    }
    if (event.key === "ArrowUp") {
      console.log("keys.up");
    }
    if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
      console.log("keys.right");
    }
    if (event.key === "ArrowDown") {
      console.log("keys.down");
    }
  };
```

I also tried to force type with the "!" as

```
event.target.parentElement!.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.focus();
```

(These`<td><button></button></td>` are placed next to each other in `<tr/>`)

and here is how I render:

```
 <table role="presentation" onKeyDown={keyDownHandler}>
        <DaysHeading />
        <DatesOfMonth
          year={dateObject.year}
          month={dateObject.month}
          datesOfMonth={dateObject.dates}
          setClickedDate={setClickedDate}
        />
      </table>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because TypeScript is seeing `event.target` as an `EventTarget` type instead of a `HTMLElement` type. You could solve this by casting `event.target` to a `HTMLElement` type like this.

```
const keyDownHandler = (event: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
          const eventTarget: HTMLElement = event.target;
          (eventTarget.parentElement.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild as HTMLButtonElement).focus();
        }
        if (event.key === "ArrowUp") {
          console.log("keys.up");
        }
        if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
          console.log("keys.right");
        }
        if (event.key === "ArrowDown") {
          console.log("keys.down");
        }
      };
```

Comment: Now I get the following error on eventTarget: 
Type 'EventTarget' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 231 more.ts(2740)
It is still seeing a EventTarget any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, try casting to `HTMLInputElement` instead of `HTMLElement`

Comment: This syntax solved it for me:
const element = event.target as HTMLElement

Answer (score 1):

just wanted to share that
in my case it worked by doing the following:

```
const clicksHandler = (e: React.TouchEvent) => {
    const eventTarget = e.target as HTMLElement;
    const parentElement = eventTarget.parentElement as HTMLDivElement;
    ...
  };
```

you can change e: React.TouchEvent to e: React.MouseEvent